# Does 528 Hz "facilitate DNA repair"?

Tags: environmental-health, dna

There is a somewhat common belief that playing a tone at 528Hz can help to facilitate DNA repair.

Examples:

> The frequency of 528 Hz supposedly has healing effects on DNA. The
>   frequency seems to influence the water molecules that surround the DNA
>   helix

-[Souls of Distortion Awakening](http://books.google.ca/books?id=XASgbACJaeEC&pg=PA171&dq=528hz%20dna&hl=en&sa=X&ei=qUVhT77CIOPV0QHeleXWBw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=528hz%20dna&f=false)

> These six frequencies, and their related effects, are as follows: Do
>   396 Hz Liberating guilt and fear Re 417 Hz Undoing situations and
>   facilitating change Mi 528 Hz Transformation and miracles (DNA repair)

-[The Subtle Body: An Encyclopedia of Your Energetic Anatomy](http://books.google.com/books?id=aTW13vNNLKMC&pg=PA142&dq=528hz%20dna&hl=en&sa=X&ei=qUVhT77CIOPV0QHeleXWBw&ved=0CDoQ6AEwAQ)

> And then last night , in studying the DNA and its correlation to the
>   Jacob's ladder of Genesis 28:12 , I learn that the sound frequency of
>   528 hz is currently being used in the repair of damaged DNA

-[Identity](http://books.google.ca/books?id=N1rXY5JVXiAC&pg=PA80&dq=528hz%20dna&hl=en&sa=X&ei=qUVhT77CIOPV0QHeleXWBw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=528hz%20dna&f=false)

This [Youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tgMQOAWeVs0) also covers the claim in more detail.

Is there any evidence for or against this claim?

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! Please find a quick intro [here](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users). We are a bit different from the other SE. Can you provide an example of the claim? I've only found [this](http://www.godlikeproductions.com/forum1/message1501418/pg1) but it doesn't seem notable at all.

Comment: I will be [temporarily closing this post](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1345/faq-my-question-was-closed-what-does-it-mean) until notability concerns are addressed.

Comment: I think it could go on Biology SE. Anyway short answer is: it's pseudoscience.

Comment: Hi Sklivvz! Thanks for the notability headsup. This 528Hz thing seems to be wrapped up in some story about "Ancient Solfeggio Frequencies". Yeah, a google search for "528 dna", or for "Solfeggio Frequencies" yields a lot of ... uh ... material. Is one or two particularly high profile links required? If not, I'm hesitant to dump 300 links to rehashed "articles" here.

Comment: Also, in terms of "fit" for skeptics, where does this question lie?

Comment: ... (notability aside)

Comment: Whoever wrote those pages clearly does not have a clue about how DNA is repaired...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

NO, it's unsubstantiated.

While I can't definitively debunk it, because no experiments were made, or published that debunk this claim, there were also no supporting scientific publications, neither experiments nor theoretical. There is simply no scientific background for this.

It's all based on [Solfeggio frequencies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solfeggio_frequencies):

> [Solfeggio frequencies] referring to a belief that a set of nine frequencies derived from numerology were used centuries ago in Gregorian and Sanskrit chants

first introduced in a 1999 book published by [a person](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonard_Horowitz)<sup>*</sup> who also claimed:

> AIDS and Ebola were engineered by the U.S. government with biological warfare and genocide in mind.

In his self published book [Emerging Viruses: AIDS and Ebola: Nature, Accident, or Intentional?](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0923550127)

It's based on speculation and Numerology, non of which is a scientific proven theory. The specific numbers for the frequencies are derived by some strange and unexplained numerologic calculation:

> The numerical values of the Solfeggio Frequences are generated by starting with the vector (1, 7, 4) and adding the vector (1, 1, 1) MOD (9). Each higher frequency is found by adding (1, 1, 1) MOD (9) to the previous lower frequency. The final frequency, when (1, 1, 1) is added to is, returns the frequency to the lowest tone (1, 7, 4).
>
> Ut = 396 Hz which reduces to 9 [reducing numbers: 3+9 = 12 = 1 + 2 = 3 ; 3+ 6 = 9]
>
> Re = 417 Hz which reduces to 3
>
> Mi = 528 Hz which reduces to 6
>
> Fa = 639 Hz which reduces to 9
>
> Sol = 741 Hz which reduces to 3
>
> La = 852 Hz which reduces to 6

<sup>*</sup> - It should be noted that the author is a dentist and has published some articles regarding Dental Health ( ["Horowitz LG" (Author) – PubMed Results](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=%22Horowitz+LG%22%5BAuthor%5D)), But he has no formal training, published papers or published research on DNA, DNA repair or any other related topic.

---

Vibrations within the [hearing range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hearing_range) or close to it might help humans heal (research in the area is not conclusive), but it's in different frequencies and with different illnesses, some examples:

[Whole-body vibration to treat low back pain: fact or fad?](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22210985)

[Acute exercise with whole-body vibration decreases wave reflection and leg arterial stiffness](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22254186)

[The effect of whole body vibration exposure on muscle function in children with cystic fibrosis: a pilot efficacy trial.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23671546)

[Transmissibility of 15-hertz to 35-hertz vibrations to the human hip and lumbar spine: determining the physiologic feasibility of delivering low-level anabolic mechanical stimuli to skeletal regions at greatest risk of fracture because of osteoporosis.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/14652479)

Comment: @Sancho, It's pseudoscience, because the exact frequency are not based on understanding of DNA structure and its repair processes, but on Numerology and on the unproven believe that they were used centuries ago by some ancient people. As the Wikipedia says: "[Solfeggio frequencies] referring to a belief that a set of nine frequencies derived from numerology were used centuries ago in Gregorian and Sanskrit chants"

Comment: It is if it's unsubstantiated.

Comment: What @Avi said.

Comment: The answer could easily be both. Pseudoscience is simply a belief that is thought to be based in science, but isn't.

Comment: @IlyaMelamed I think you meant "*definitively* debunk" not "*defiantly* debunk".

Comment: @called2voyage, you are correct, suggest it as an edit so you'll get the rep.

Comment: The Wkiepedia link to Mr Horowitz seems to be dead

Comment: The above is obvious pseudoscience, but it is possible that there has been confusion (accidental or deliberate) with speculative but scientifically based concerns about microwave and terahertz radiation, which *could* agitate water molecules, and might also be able to influence the noncovalent interactions of proteins with DNA.  See e.g. https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/31015556/  Current political controversies involving 5G may be more interesting in this light.

Comment: Even if we wanted to take it seriously, we couldn't. The Solfeggio scale (in English, the "sol-fa" scale) is the common "do, re, mi" scale (with "ti" missing), with each note being about either the 12th root of 2 or the 6th root of 2 higher in frequency than the one before it. The definitions in the question has the same named notes, but they are spaced much too far apart in frequency. And calling the first one "Ut" is over the top; it was renamed to "Do" 4 centuries ago.